# Expanding a quadratic term

Tags: statistics

In a derivation involving the normal distribution, I saw this used:

$$ \sum (X_i - \mu)^2 = \sum(X_i - \bar{X} + \bar{X} - \mu)^2 = \sum(X_i - \bar{X})^2 + \sum(\bar{X} - \mu)^2$$.

I don't follow the last step. Is this a general trick/formula that one can use, with any value in the place of $\bar{X}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its same as
$(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+2AB$

So there is an additional term but it vanishes.

$$\begin{align*}\sum_i (X_i - \mu)^2 &= \sum_i(X_i - \bar{X} + \bar{X} - \mu)^2 \\&= \sum_i(X_i - \bar{X})^2 + \sum_i(\bar{X} - \mu)^2+2(\bar X - \mu )\sum_i(X_i - \bar{X})\end{align*}$$

The last term vanishes because of which property?

> \begin{align} \text{The sum of deviations of the items from their arithmetic mean is always zero} \end{align}

Comment: Basically $\sum_i(X_i-\bar X)=\sum_i X_i-n\bar X=0$ since $\bar X=\frac1n\sum_iX_i$.